# java - NullPointerException in linked lists finding char

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, linked-list

```
public class LString{
   char data;      //chars stored in this node
   LString next;   //link to next LString node 

  public LString(char newdata){
     data = newdata;
  }

  public LString(char newdata, LString newnext){
     data = newdata;
     next = newnext;
  }

  public LString(){
  }

  //create a front of list
  LString front;

  //create length of list
  int length;

  /*Construct an LString object. The LString object will represent the
  same list of chars as original. That is, the newly created LString is a
  "copy" of the parameter original.*/

  public LString(String original){
     LString curr = front;
     for(int i = 0; i < original.length(); i++){
        curr.data = original.charAt(i);
        curr = curr.next;
        length++;
     }
  }
}

public class test{
     public static void main(String[] args){
        LString myList = new LString("hi");
     }
}
```

The following code should put the string "hi", into a linked list of chars, where each letter of hi, is one node of the list. When ran, it gives a nullpointerexception pointing to the line curr.data = original.charAt(i);. Why is there a null pointer exception there? Thank you

Comment: do you have an example of your main driver program, showing how you are using this class?

Comment: I don't see `front` being initialized anywhere? and yet you assign it to `LString curr` so therefore that will be null. So change `LString front` to `LString front = new LString();`

Answer (score 1):

In your loop:

```
public LString(String original){
 LString curr = front;
 for(int i = 0; i < original.length(); i++){
    curr.data = original.charAt(i);
    curr = curr.next;
    length++;
 }
```

}

The first iteration through, you set `curr.data` to the first character in the original String. You then set `curr` to the value at `curr.next` - which is null.

Therefore, the second iteration, when you try to access `curr.data`, curr is null so the exception is thrown.

You need to take into account that on the first character of the string, you haven't yet set the `front`, so setting next is premature. Change your code to check for the first element and don't set next in this case:

```
public LString(String original){
  LString curr = null;

  for(int i = 0; i < original.length(); i++){
    char ch = original.charAt(i);

    if(i == 0){
        front = new LString(ch);
        curr = front;
    }
    else{
        curr.next = new LString(ch);
        curr = curr.next;
    }
    length++;
  }
}
```